# how to use variable +=

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to use variable in scrollTop() function `'+=' + itemHeight + 'px'` http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mVwOwy

```
var itemHeight = $(item).height(); // item height

        //keyup
        if (event.which == 38) {
            $(box).stop().animate({scrollTop: '-=' + itemHeight + 'px'}, 100);
            event.preventDefault();

            console.log('-='+ itemHeight + 'px');

            // if active item is first child
            if (active.index() !== 0) {
                $(active).removeClass('active').prev().addClass('active');
                console.log('123');
            }
        }
```

Comment: Remove ` + 'px'` pixel is the default unit anyway

Comment: You need to provide MCVE replicating your issue. `still not work` doesn't really help...

Comment: Can you create live demo on StackSnippet/JSfiddle

Comment: Maybe `event.which` not working in browser, try `event.keyCode`.

Comment: All modern browsers provide debugging tools _normally_ opened by clicking on `F12`. Go to `console` tab and add the errors if any, in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edits**
Your code was good, you just did one tiny thing wrong.
You where using "-=" on your keydown as well, which was the reversed effect you wanted. I changed it to "+=" which adds the height to the current value and that did the trick. The code below is what you need :)

*keyup*

```
  $(box).stop().animate({
    scrollTop: '-=' + itemHeight
  }, 100);
```

*keydown*

```
  $(box).stop().animate({
    scrollTop: '+=' + itemHeight
  }, 100);
```

**Snippet**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  //item
  var box = $('.sel-wrapper');
  var item = $('.sel-wrapper li');
  var active = $('.sel-wrapper li.active');
  var itemHeight = $(item).outerHeight(); // item height

  console.log(itemHeight);

  $(item).on('click', function() {
    $(item).removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });

  //

  var counter = 0;
  $(document).keydown(function(event) {

    var box = $('.sel-wrapper');
    var item = $('.sel-wrapper li');
    var active = $('.sel-wrapper li.active');

    //keyup
    if (event.which == 38) {
      $(box).stop().animate({
        scrollTop: '-=' + itemHeight
      }, 100);
      event.preventDefault();

      // if active item is first child
      if (active.index() !== 0) {
        $(active).removeClass('active').prev().addClass('active');
        console.log('123');
      }
    }

    //keydown
    if (event.which == 40) {
      $(box).stop().animate({
        scrollTop: '+=' + itemHeight
      }, 100);
      event.preventDefault();

      // if active item is last child
      if (active.index() !== item.length - 1) {
        $(active).removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
      }

    }

    counter++;

  });

});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.row {
  width: 100%;
}
.sel-wrapper {
  padding: 10px 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.sel-wrapper ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.sel-wrapper li {
  padding: 4px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.sel-wrapper li:hover {
  background: rgba(60, 63, 65, 0.49);
}
.sel-wrapper li.active {
  background: #1a8bff;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sel-wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li class="active">123</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>10</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```